# Why is CMake using the wrong library search path flag style when cross-compiling Windows binaries from Linux using clang-cl and lld-link?

Tags: cmake

I'm attempting to cross-compile Windows binaries from Linux via CMake using clang-cl and lld-link. I think I'm very close to a working solution.

Here is my toolchain file:

```
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME Generic)
set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER /usr/bin/clang-cl)
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER /usr/bin/clang-cl)
set(CMAKE_RC_COMPILER /usr/bin/llvm-rc-15)
set(CMAKE_AR /usr/bin/llvm-ar-15)
add_compile_options(-Wno-ignored-attributes -EHa)
add_link_options(-fuse-ld=lld-link)
include_directories(
    /home/workspace/sysroots/windows/crt/include
    /home/workspace/sysroots/windows/sdk/include/ucrt
    /home/workspace/sysroots/windows/sdk/include/shared
    /home/workspace/sysroots/windows/sdk/include/um
)
link_directories(
    /home/workspace/sysroots/windows/sdk/lib/ucrt/x86_64
    /home/workspace/sysroots/windows/crt/lib/x86_64
    /home/workspace/sysroots/windows/sdk/lib/um/x86_64
)
```

The test compile succeeds but not the linking. Here is the error:

```
/usr/bin/clang-cl -m64 -m64     -fuse-ld=lld-link CMakeFiles/cmTC_dd439.dir/Debug/testCCompiler.c.obj -o Debug/cmTC_dd439 -L/home/workspace/sysroots/windows/sdk/lib/ucrt/x86_64   -L/home/workspace/sysroots/windows/crt/lib/x86_64   -L/home/workspace/sysroots/windows/sdk/lib/um/x86_64  && :
    FAILED: Debug/cmTC_dd439 
    : && /usr/bin/clang-cl -m64 -m64     -fuse-ld=lld-link CMakeFiles/cmTC_dd439.dir/Debug/testCCompiler.c.obj -o Debug/cmTC_dd439 -L/home/workspace/sysroots/windows/sdk/lib/ucrt/x86_64   -L/home/workspace/sysroots/windows/crt/lib/x86_64   -L/home/workspace/sysroots/windows/sdk/lib/um/x86_64  && :
    clang: warning: unknown argument ignored in clang-cl: '-L/home/workspace/sysroots/windows/sdk/lib/ucrt/x86_64' [-Wunknown-argument]
    clang: warning: unknown argument ignored in clang-cl: '-L/home/workspace/sysroots/windows/crt/lib/x86_64' [-Wunknown-argument]
    clang: warning: unknown argument ignored in clang-cl: '-L/home/workspace/sysroots/windows/sdk/lib/um/x86_64' [-Wunknown-argument]
    lld-link: error: could not open 'libcmt.lib': No such file or directory
    lld-link: error: could not open 'oldnames.lib': No such file or directory
    clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
    ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

I can see that CMake uses the wrong command line argument `-L` to set the library search paths. If I manually try to execute the command but change it to `/link` and `/LIBPATH:<path>` then it works. Those are the flags that clang-cl use to forward arguments to the linker and then how lld-link sets the search path.

So here is my question: Can I somehow force/trick CMake into thinking that it's using `cl.exe` so that it passes the correct arguments?

Thank you!

Edit:
I'm using CMake version 3.26.1

Edit:
I missed a part of the CMake output:

```
-- The C compiler identification is Clang 15.0.7 with MSVC-like command-line
-- The CXX compiler identification is Clang 15.0.7 with MSVC-like command-line
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - failed
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/clang-cl
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/clang-cl - broken
```

Now I'm extra confused because it actually say `The C compiler identification is Clang 15.0.7 with MSVC-like command-line`.

Edit:
Outputting some debug information

```
-- CMAKE_C_COMPILER_ID               = Clang
-- CMAKE_C_SIMULATE_ID               = MSVC
-- CMAKE_C_COMPILER FRONTEND_VARIANT = MSVC
-- CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID               = Clang
-- CMAKE_CXX_SIMULATE_ID               = MSVC
-- CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER FRONTEND_VARIANT = MSVC
```

Comment: Set [CMAKE_*_COMPILER_FRONTEND_VARIANT](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_LANG_COMPILER_FRONTEND_VARIANT.html)?

Comment: @teapot418 I have tried that but nothing happens. If I understand it correctly, it sets those variables from the compiler identification?

Comment: As your are cross-compiling for **Windows**, then set `CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME` to `Windows`, not to `Generic`.

Answer (score 0):

@Tsyvarev Provided the correct solution!

I had to set `CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME` to `Windows`, not to `Generic`. Another follow-up fix needed was providing `CMAKE_MT`.